# Gradient of matrix product with respect to matrix

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

If a matrix $Y$ is defined as the product of two matrices $X$ and $W$ ie $Y=X.W$ , how do we compute the gradients $\partial Y/\partial W$ and $\partial Y/\partial X$. The dimensions of matrix $X$ is $m*d$,those of $W$ are $d*h$ and those of $Y$  $m*h$ .

I have a basic knowledge of matrices and their multiplication but have no knowledge of matrix calculus. Any recommendation about books regarding this subject would be appreciated. My current field of study is neural networks and I need to study matrix calculation to perform backpropagation.

Comment: The map $W \to X W$ is linear. The differential of a linear map is always itself.

Comment: so ∂Y/∂X = X and ∂Y/∂W = W ?

Answer (score 1):

The gradient of a matrix with respect to a matrix is a 4th order tensor, so it's best to use index notation.
$$\eqalign{
Y_{ik} &= X_{ij}W_{jk} \cr
dY_{ik} &= dX_{ij}\,W_{jk} + X_{ij}\,dW_{jk}  \cr
\cr
\bigg(\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}\bigg)_{ikpq}
 &=\frac{\partial Y_{ik}}{\partial X_{pq}}
  = \frac{\partial X_{ij}}{\partial X_{pq}}\,W_{jk} 
  = \delta_{ip}\,\delta_{jq}\,W_{jk}
  = \delta_{ip}\,W_{qk} \cr
\cr
\bigg(\frac{\partial Y}{\partial W}\bigg)_{ikpq}
 &= \frac{\partial Y_{ik}}{\partial W_{pq}}
  = X_{ij}\,\frac{\partial W_{jk}}{\partial W_{pq}} 
  = X_{ij}\,\delta_{jp}\,\delta_{kq}
  = X_{ip}\,\delta_{qk} \cr
\cr
}$$

Answer (score 0):

I would write it this way: $F(X, W) = X W$,
$$DF(X, W)\cdot(H, K) = H W + X K$$
where $DF$ is the differential of $F$. This notation is less ambiguous than partial derivatives. Note that for a continuous bilinear map, one alway has
$$DF(X, W)\cdot (H, K) = F(H, W) + F(X, K)$$
One can also use $dF$ or $F^\prime$ instead of $DF$. The partial derivative $\partial F/\partial X$ would be the linear map $H\mapsto H W$.

Comment: could you refer me to some material or book that I can study, because I cannot understand what you have written. How do I arrive at a matrix form of the two gradients?

Comment: Can you give the definition of "the two gradients"? I think you need a general book in differential calculus in multidimensional spaces, but unfortunately I don't have a reference in english.

Comment: I need to calculate the gradients of the matrices X and W with respect to a scalar C so that I can update them using updates like  X=X-∂C/∂X in order to minimize C. To get the gradient wrt to scalar, I am using the chain rule and for that I require the gradients ∂Y/∂W and ∂Y/∂X

Comment: Please consider adding the full minimization problem to your question.